# Ошибка при копировании массива в процедуре C++

Tags: c++

После вызова процедуры выдает какой-то мусор и ошибку. В чем может быть причина?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory.h>
using namespace std;

void proc(string b[]){
    string e[3];
    memcpy(e, b, 3*sizeof(string));
}

int main(){
    string d[] = {"1", "2", "3"};
    proc(d);
    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++){
        cout << d[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в копировании посредством `memcpy` экземпляров класса с нетривиальным копированием. Класс `std::string` управляет (потенциально динамически выделенным) массивом и должен копироваться исключительно посредством вызова конструктора копирования / копирующего оператора = / метода `assign`. После перетирания строк в массиве `e` содержимым массива `d` все строки оказываются необратимо повреждены и в появлется Неопределенное поведение.